# phpmyadmin 2002 error

Tags: php, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have got this error message:

*#2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)*

I use Ubuntu 11.10... and Xampp

I used the google, and I saw this solution:

> $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock'; or
>   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';

But these lines in the config.inc.php file, don't fix the problem.

Can somebody help me? What else can I do?

I want to learn php :) But there are a lot of problem... Maybe on Windows 7, there isn't this problem?

Comment: Have you checked that mysql server is up and running? Try: sudo service mysql restart

Comment: Are you sure the MySQL daemon is running?

Comment: @guiman I have tried, and the terminal write out this: mysql: unrecognized service

Comment: @DaveRandom: No I am not sure, I am beginner, I have started the php and mysql today :). And I dont know what is the MySQL daemon, but the xampp writes out... Oh I now see this line in the terminal:
XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL

How can I start the MySql?

Comment: Seems like you dont have installed the mysql server, try doing this: sudo apt-get install mysql-server , and then try again the command i mentioned before.

Comment: I have done! :) installed the mysql, and restart xampp.
Here is what writes out the terminal after the command:
mysql start/running, process 8894
But it still doesn't fix the original problem

Comment: And an another problem at the localhost/phpmyadmin:
'The set configuration of the control user connection failed.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as you are telling that your are just  started with php using ubuntu my advise is to start from scratch, here it's a small guite:

- Install all you will be needing:

  sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server phpmyadmin
- Once all it's installed you will be using the following directories

  /var/www -- here its where your server stores your pages

  /var/log/apache2/ -- here it's where logs are stored (quite helpful when apache 
  fails,check out the error.log file in that directory)

  /etc/apache2 -- apache configuration lives here

  /etc/php5/cli -- this is where configuration for php5 console live (when you use ~$ php5 test.php the configuration is read from here)

  /etc/php5/apache2 this is where configuration for php5 server live (when you access from a browser like http://localhost/test.php )

The configuration files out of the box dont need to be modified (maybe for more advance uses you will need to modify them)

To uninstall xamp here its a thread might be helful: http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=135389 . First remove xamp and then follow my instructions

Comment: Ok, I have done it! And How Can I countinue? The http://localhost/test.php   writes out: 404 not found ...

Comment: That normal, thats because you did not created a test.php file in /var/ww. Do this: sudo echo "<?php echo 'Hello world';?>" > /var/www/test.php ; sudo chmod 777 /var/www/test.php;    And then try again that url

Comment: That command creates a test.php file in /var/www that contains some basic code written in php. From now on, you should start reading some tutorials on php. Here its a good starting point: http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: Hm, The terminal writes out: premission denied
But I found an index.php file in the var/www/index.php
And it writes out this in the browser:
It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Comment: The permission denied its because you have missed the "sudo". Anyways, being able to open the index.php file means you are ready to get started. You dont need to do anymore to start coding in php. Remember to check this out http://www.w3schools.com/php/

Comment: Ok I will be check out. But no, I have not missed the "sudo". But thanks everything!